# Why we add templates path in DIRS in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am confused here to find the proper answer why we add templates in DIRS in settings.py like below:

```
TEMPLATES =[

         ....
         'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
         ....
]
```

I have checked that if I don't add templates in DIRS then the tempates and leave it empty then templates is also working. Can anyone please explain what's the difference? Many Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a new Django project, the default settings put `'APP_DIRS': True,`. This means that Django searches the templates directory for all the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/#overriding-from-an-app-s-template-directory)).

You can use `DIRS` if you want Django to search other directories for templates. The example in your question `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],` makes Django search the `templates` directory in the project directory.